# How to get string in format yyyy-mm from datetime in c#

Tags: c#, string, datetime, tostring

I have a DateTime in format mm/dd/yyyy and I need to get string that would be looks like "yyyy-mm".

I know, that I can use ToString() with fomat inside, but for my format it doesn't work.

For this DateTime: `1/31/1999 12:00:00 AM`

I got this: `"1999-00"` string using `ToString("yyyy-mm")`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you want `ToString("yyyy-MM")`

`mm` is used for minutes.  For months:

`M - The month, from 1 through 12.`

`MM - The month, from 01 through 12.`

`MMM - The abbreviated name of the month.`

`MMMM - The full name of the month.`

[See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) for all formats

Comment: OMG! Thanks! Exactly! Am I so stupid? =) Will accept in few minutes!

Comment: You may want to expand your answer to explicitly say that `MM` is used for a two digit month or similar.